# Having controller `create` method call `update` method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working on my first ajax project to add a star rating system to an album `show` page. I followed [this](http://eighty-b.tumblr.com/post/1569674815/creating-an-ajaxified-star-rating-system-in-rails-3) example, and everything works. However I noticed that until I reloaded my page the `create` action would always be called creating multiple entries for each `user`/ `album`.

So basically my Star database got this:

```
<Star id: 9, created_at: ..., updated_at: ..., user_id: 2, album_id: 8, rating: 3>,
<Star id: 10, created_at: ..., updated_at: ..., user_id: 2, album_id: 8, rating: 5>,
<Star id: 11, created_at: ..., updated_at: ..., user_id: 2, album_id: 8, rating: 3>,
```

Obviously unacceptable.

My first idea was to `delete` the previous rating prior to creating a new one, but instead went with this in the `controller`

```
class StarsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    star_rated(@album)
    @star = Star.new(params[:star])
    @star.album_id = @album.id
    @star.user_id = current_user.id
    if @star.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to album_url(@album), :notice => "Rating logged" }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def update(star = nil)
    @star = star
    @star ||= current_user.stars.find_by_album_id(params[:album_id])
    if @star.update_attributes(params[:star])
      format.html { redirect_to album_url(@album), :notice => "Rating logged" }
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def star_rated(album)
    if star = current_user.stars.find_by_album_id(album.id)
      update(star)
    end
  end
end
```

And it works, and I'm happy except that I've been searching for a little while now to see if anyone else has done something similar, and I haven't seen anything (although I did see some someone implement my original `delete` idea) which makes me worried that it's bad practice.

It also allows `update` to take an argument, and I just read about SQL injections last week and am now worried in general about things being injected into places. Does allowing `update` to take an argument present any security worries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, adding argument to controller action is safe. It still shouldn't be done, though. Extract update logic into a method of itself, and call it from both `create` and `update` actions.

Comment: Do you mean repeat the logic within `update` in another method that does take an argument, like`alternate_update(star)` and leave update untouched?